# Typescript type error when filtering undefined from array

Tags: typescript

I want to filter undefined items from an array like so

```
type Kind = 'foo' | 'bar'

const someFunc = () : Array<{ kind: Kind, name: string }> => {
    return [{ kind: 'foo', name: 'a' }].filter(x => x !== undefined)
}
```

Gives the following type error:

```
Type '{ kind: string; name: string; }[]' is not assignable to type '{ 
kind: Kind; name: string; }[]'.
Type '{ kind: string; name: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ 
kind: Kind; name: string; }'.
Types of property 'kind' are incompatible.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Kind'.
```

Why does it fail, and how to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new variable to declare the type of `kind`. This is because TypeScript is inferring that kind is a string.

```
type Kind = "foo" | "bar"

const someFunc = (): Array<{kind: Kind, name: string}> => {
    const kind: Kind = 'foo'
    return [{ kind, name: 'a' }].filter(x => x !== undefined)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because TypeScript is inferring the type of your array from `[{ kind: 'foo', name: 'a' }]`. If you tell it what the type of the array is, it'll be happier. :)

```
type Kind = 'foo' | 'bar'

const someFunc = (): Array<{ kind: Kind; name: string }> => {
    const array: Array<{kind: Kind; name: string}> = [{ kind: 'foo', name: 'a' }];
    return array.filter(x => x !== undefined)
}
```